# Eloquent/Query Builder for more complicated table structures

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

OK so this probably isn't the biggest problem in the world and I'm sure someone will be able to help me out with where I'm going wrong. Here's a few facts before I get to my problem:

- Laravel 5 & mysql
- I have 3 main tables: `meetups`, `events` and `locations`
- I also one pivot table: `event_location`
- Meetups `hasMany` Events
- Events `belongsTo` Meetups
- Events `belongsToMany` Locations
- Locations `belongsToMany` Events

**The problem**

I'm currently trying to search the *locations* (via a form – i.e. `Input::get('data')`), and this would bring up all *events* that have that *location*, and all *meetups* that associate with that *event*.

Within my `SearchController`, I have the following:

```
// Get the searched data
$data = Input::get('data');

// Get all location, which are 'LIKE' the inputted data.
$locations = Location::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $data .'%')->get();
```

At this point I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to access the events from each location and after that I'd need a get the meetup that corresponds with that location, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Can this be done with `joins()` or would I loop through the `$locations` variable and get the `->events` for each of those and put them into an array? Or, should I be using `DB::` and running a custom query?

Comment: Do you have models appropriately set up, with the relationships described above? If so, you should be able to let Eloquent do all the heavy lifting using something along the lines of
`Location::where( ... )->with('events.meetups')->get();`
That would join your Event model based on the Location->events() relationship, and the Meetup model based on the Event->meetups() relationship.

Comment: Thanks @iavery, I did have to change the relationship to be `belongsToMany()` between events and meetups but that seems to have sorted my problem. Eloquent is so cool! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: It is pretty mind bogglingly awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

See @iavery's comment, it seems the following works when you have all `belongsToMany` relationships:

`Location::where( ... )->with('events.meetups')->get();`